# Mac freezes during usb osx boot install

Tags: macos, mac, usb, freeze, bootloader

My brother-in-law gave me his old Mac Pro (the big gray tower, circe 2009) as a hand-me-down.  It was working perfectly fine but he wiped the hard drive totally clean before I got it (he was intially going to throw it away!).  I am looking to re-install osx to get the computer up and running but need some help.

I setup a usb boot installer for Yosemite using Disc Drill on my Macbook Air.  When I plug the usb into the Mac Pro and turn it on while holding the option key the gray screen opens with the orange usb icon.  However, when I click on that icon to take the next step the screen turns completely gray and nothing else happens.  I have let the computer "run" with this blank gray screen overnight and nothing changed so I don't think its a matter of waiting for the installer to load.

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on what the problem could be or a next step to do some diagnostics.  Any insight would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: It may depend how precise your 'circa 09' is. If it's actually an 08 model, these are much harder to boot from USB [I've never managed it in 9 years] The 09s are easy. You can check the serial number on the backplate against EveryMac's [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) to be certain. Add the model to your question & we can go from there... Also, in the meantime, see what happens if you hold Cmd/R at the boot chimes - maybe he left a recovery partition on there...

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the detailed response and sorry for the delay getting back to you. You are right it’s a ‘06 - ‘08 model based on that site. I’m certain he wiped the disk clean and there’s no boot partition. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry didn’t answer your question. Model A1186. Serial G872917YUPZ

Comment: Ah, that's an original 1,1 - the latest OS it can run [without some tweaking] is Lion 10.7.5, which you'll need to buy from from Apple. Google 'os x lion cd' will turn up your nation's Apple Store link. However, to get to it, you will first need Snow Leopard, 10.6.8 which was the last available on optical disk. Again, Googling 'os x 10.6.8 cd' will turn up the required link. Alternatively, you could lug it down to an Apple Store & they'll do it for you.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks.  Do you know how to get the CD/DVD tray to open without the OS installed?

Comment: Hold the mouse button down at the chimes [which always meant you needed to reboot twice, 2nd time with the CD in ..or if it really won't behave at all without an OS, the optical bay doors simply slide down with very little pressure & you can poke with a paper-clip like any other

Comment: @Tetsujin - Holding the mouse down worked perfectly, thank you!  I will get a hold of a Snow Leopard installation DVD and see if that works.  I really *really* appreciate your help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With a model that old, I think you'd have better results not trying to boot from USB.  Does this Mac have some version of a CD drive? Or do you have access to a bootable hard drive to install OS/X onto the Mac Pro?  Once it's powered up, you should be able to open the CD/DVD drive with the button, or look for a small hole close to the drive.  Old Macs had an emergency CD tray open switch you can activate with a paper clip in that hole.

Comment: Given @Tetsujin advice above I abandoned the USB option and got my hands on a Snow Leopard installation DVD.  I used holding the mouse down on boot to get the DVD tray open and have tried turning the computer on holding down the "C" key but haven't had any luck.  I can hear the DVD spinning as if the computer is reading from it but eventually, each time, it gives up and takes me to the flashing question mark folder screen.  Any ideas?